# how to configure max limit on the number of documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB as my app database.

I have a collection `books` & need to set an upper cap on the number of documents. I thought & tried with marking the collection as capped collection

```
books.createCollection({capped: true, max: 1000})
```

What it is doing/does by default on reaching the count to 1000 it overrides/purges the oldest document however that's not **What I need. on reaching the limit, it should not accept any more documents & should throw an error on trying to do so**

So how can I override this default behavior of capped collection or curious if mongodb has some other way to achieve this

Please suggest. Thanks!

P.S. -> *Scheduler in on my trail list but keeping it as the later option*

Comment: Do you consider doing a collection size check before inserting on the application level?

Comment: Or, use Change Streams to perform the collection size check (in which case you wont need the Capped collection).

Comment: @ray I know it could be one way but again keeping it when there is no other better way

Comment: @ray, while I'm also of opinion that counting the number of documents (when the limit is 100,000) could be time-intensive. what you think?